# Wrong Ruby version in a deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, centos, localhost

This is the output I do get for running rails console on Heroku:

```
❯ heroku run rails console -a my-app
Running rails console on ⬢ my-app... up, run.4507 (Standard-1X)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/auth/ssl.rb:13: warning: constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated
/app/app/lib/proxy/choose.rb:23: warning: constant Net::HTTPServerException is deprecated
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.4.2)
irb(main):001:0>
```

What I don't understand is; my ruby version is **not** `2.6.0`, but `2.6.5` as specified in my Gemfile.

Showing incorrect Ruby version in a warning is not specific to Heroku. When I run rails console on a CentOS, this is what I get:

```
[my-app@pinternal2 ogirginc]$ cd /my-app-app/src/ && /usr/local/bin/envdir /my-app-app/env /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/bundle exec rails c
/my-app-app/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/auth/ssl.rb:13: warning: constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated
/my-app-app/src/app/lib/proxy/choose.rb:23: warning: constant Net::HTTPServerException is deprecated
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.4.2)
2.6.5 :001 >
```

What makes this more confusing for me is running console on my local machine (macOS):

```
❯ bundle exec bin/rails console
/Users/ogirginc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@my_app/gems/httpi-2.4.2/lib/httpi/auth/ssl.rb:13: warning: constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS is deprecated
/Users/ogirginc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@my_app/gems/shoulda-matchers-2.8.0/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_inclusion_of_matcher.rb:251: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4.2)
2.6.5 :001 >
```

Does anyone know why the depreciation warning's path does include the wrong version (`2.6.0`) of Ruby?

Comment: Can it be related with recent openSSL gem update? https://rubygems.org/gems/openssl

Comment: Turns out it is not related to a specific gem! ‍♂️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. When installing Ruby as a system executable (or using the default installer without explicit gem path), the gem path will always use the major Ruby version as the path component for gems. This is so that you can update the minor version without having to reinstall all your gems.

So any 2.6.x version, will have its gems installed in `/...something.../2.6.0/gems` by default.

This is a different story when using RVM or rbenv, where you can explicitly specify your gemsets for each single Ruby installation. We can see this in your RVM installation, where the gemset path is very specific and tied directly to that particular Ruby executable.